# python oracledb - update statement in procedure is executed without effect

Tags: python, oracle, stored-procedures, sql-update, python-oracledb

I have following oracle procedure that I want to trigger via python's oracledb:

```
create or replace procedure update_reported_delta(
    update_tbl_name in varchar2,
    update_key_col in varchar2,
    update_key_vals in varchar2
    )     
    AUTHID CURRENT_USER -- needed to grant create/update table right within stored procedure
AS

    sql_cmd varchar(32767);

BEGIN
    
    sql_cmd:= 'UPDATE ' || update_tbl_name || '
        SET DELTA_REPORTED = ''Y''
            WHERE '|| update_key_col ||' in 
            ('||update_key_vals||') AND DELTA_REPORTED IS NULL';
    dbms_output.put_line(sql_cmd);
    execute immediate sql_cmd;           
END;
```

When executed via SQL-Developer like:

```
set serveroutput on;
begin
    update_reported_delta('my_tbl', 'my_id_col', '''MY_ID_VAL''');
end;
```

the corresponding records are updated and the sql_cmd variable looks like:

```
UPDATE my_tbl
        SET DELTA_REPORTED = 'Y'
            WHERE my_id_col in 
            ('MY_ID_VAL') AND DELTA_REPORTED IS NULL
```

If I execute it using the oracledb library via python I see that the created sql statement is exactly the same. However, the values are not updated (I reset the `DELTA_REPORTED` column to `null` again, before executing the same statement - when the python console output `sql_cmd` is copy pasted into the SQL-Developer it also works...)

My python code looks like:

```
        if debug==False:
            cursor.callproc(procedure_name, params_list)
        elif debug==True:
            print("""START DEBUG SESSION - OUTPUT ENABLED""")
            cursor.callproc("dbms_output.enable")
            cursor.callproc(procedure_name, params_list)
            self.__write_debug_output_to_console(cursor)
        print(f"Executed {procedure_name} successfully!")
```

where `procedure_name`= UPDATE_REPORTED_DELTA and `params_list` looks like `['my_tbl', 'my_id_col', "'MY_ID_VAL'"]`.

I see that the procedure is triggered via python, as I can initiate errors which throws ORA-Errors in my Python Console - when e.g. adding non-existent table columns to my sql query within the procedure...

Any help/hint appreciated!

Comment: in your procedure you do not commit, do you do that anywhere in the python code? If you check the update after the code exists, without a commit, (or from any other session while it is still running, you won't see the update taking effect

Comment: @gsalem That's awesome! I added `commit;` to my stored procedure and now it works! Was not aware that SQL Developer kind of `auto commits` against the Database with my current settings.

Comment: No, sqldev does NOT autocommit, but you were testing the result of the update is the same session, and so you see the effect of the update. In python, if you did not commit, the updates are rolled back when the script exits.